# Which (better Intel) CPU gives the highest per-core speed?

Tags: processor

I am thinking about buying a CPU to use for a Minecraft server -- the problem is that Minecraft is very bad at hyperthreading, only actually using one core. So it doesn't matter if my CPU has 2, 4 or 16 cores -- I need just one to be the quickest.

Which one and, more important, how should I choose?

Comment: Why not email a server hosting company and ask what they use? IME, tech departments tend to be quite willing to share information.

Comment: i7 7700K should be the fastest. i5 7600K and i3 7350K are cheaper and only slightly slower. If you don't overclock you could use the equivalent non k model to save some money, but those are slightly slower, even at stock clocks. See [Kaby Lake on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaby_Lake_(CPU)#Desktop_Processors)